# Jquery beautyofCode show code lines from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, code-formatting

I'm using BeautyofCode jQuery plugin, but i can't understand 1 thing.

I submit a piece of code by a simple textarea then save that into db record.

Once i retrieve piece of code from db as a string js plugin show me code all in 1 line, wondering how to split lines when submitting code from textarea? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line breaks are probably being saved as `\n` and when you look at what comes from the database you don't see the line-breaks because HTML does not recognize `\n`, what you need to do is convert all `\n`'s to `<br />`'s so the HTML will display appropriately.